# How to set the color for the NavigationBar on Android before launching the app

Tags: android, colors, navigationbar

I need to change the color of the NavigatioBar even before the app is shown to the user.
Now I have this situation after clicking on the icon of my application - screenshot 1.

[image]

I managed to change the color of the Navigation Bar after downloading the app. This is shown in screenshot - 2 .
I searched a lot about this, looked in the project files, but it didn't work out. At the same time, I saw that this is possible and, for example, with Yandex Maps, after clicking on the application, the color of the Navigation Bar turns white, even though it was red. Screenshot - 3.

screenshot 2:

[image]

screenshot 3:

[image]